# Storing IPv6 Addresses in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

As has been requested in "[ipv6-capable inet_aton and inet_ntoa functions needed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34037)", there is currently no MySQL function for storing IPv6 addresses. What would be the recommended data type/function for storing/inserting? (I don't intend to store them as a string). I also don't want to separate the IPv6 address into 2 INT's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store IPv6 in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049681/store-ipv6-in-database)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

How about:

```
BINARY(16)
```

That should be effective enough.

Currently there is no function to convert textual IPv6 addresses from/to binary in the MySQL server, as noted in that bug report. You either need to do it in your application or possibly make a UDF (User-Defined Function) in the MySQL server to do that.

**UPDATE:**

MySQL 5.6.3 has support for IPv6 addresses, see the following: "[INET6_ATON(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton)".

The data type is `VARBINARY(16)` instead of `BINARY(16)` as I suggested earlier. The only reason for this is that the MySQL functions work for both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. `BINARY(16)` is fine for storing only IPv6 addresses and saves one byte. `VARBINARY(16)` should be used when handling both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses.

An implementation for older versions of MySQL and MariaDB, see the following: "[EXTENDING MYSQL 5 WITH IPV6 FUNCTIONS](http://labs.watchmouse.com/2009/10/extending-mysql-5-with-ipv6-functions/)".

Comment: Perfect timing! Just a month or so after I posted the question :P

Comment: Be aware that you'll have to convert using `INET6_NTOA` every time you retrieve the address if you want it as inserted.

Answer (score 14):

No one has posted a full working answer (and lots of examples use the Windows `::1` which can be *very* misleading for live (or "production") environments) any where (at least that I can find) so here is:

1. The format to store with.
2. Example `INSERT` query using a reasonably complex IPv6 IP address.
3. Example `SELECT` query that you will be able to `echo` the IPv6 IP address back to the client.
4. Troubleshooting to ensure you haven't missed any legacy code.

I changed all the column names to `ipv6` to reflect that they *properly* support IPv6 (and that allows you to keep the old column `ip` intact). It is possible to store the `ip` column in the `ipv6` column and then just `DROP` the `ip` column once you're certain the conversion has worked; when I actually have time I'll add that to this post.

**IPv6 Data Type**

As has been mentioned `VARBINARY 16` is the desirable way to go until AMD blesses us with 128 bit CPUs and the databases are updated to support 128 bit integers (did I say that correctly?). IPv6 is 128 bit, not 64 bit.

```
CREATE TABLE `example`
(
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ipv6` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

---

**IPv6 INSERT Query**

We obviously need to store an IPv6 IP address before we can `SELECT` it; here is the **PHP / SQL** code:

```
$ipv6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,'FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329');
$query1 = "INSERT INTO example (ipv6) VALUES (INET6_ATON('$ipv6'));";
```

---

**IPv6 SELECT Query**

The **PHP / SQL** code:

```
$ipv6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,'FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329');
$query2 = "SELECT INET6_NTOA(ipv6) AS ipv6 FROM example WHERE ipv6=INET6_ATON('$ipv6');";
```

This will return `fe80::202:b3ff:fe1e:8329`; no, not the full IPv6 (which is `FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329`), it's a condensed / shorthand version. There is code to make it the formal full-length version but this is to save myself and others time because *this* Q/A is the one that keeps coming up.

**Important:** just because *some* IPv6 addresses *look* like they'd fit in to `bigint` does *not* imply two minutes later someone with a larger IPv6 address won't stop by and wreak havoc.

Hopefully this will save some folks from the insanity of opening another two dozen tabs. When I have time in the future I'll add the extra PHP code that extends the condensed IPv6 to the full formal format.

---

**Troubleshooting**

If for some reason storing and/or retrieving IPv6 addresses is not working for you then grab yourself a copy of [Advanced Find and Replace](http://www.abacre.com/afr/) (works faster in Wine than Linux's native `grep`); use this *predominantly* for finding, not replacing. Ensure that your code is *consistent* everywhere in your software.

- All `$ip` variables *must* be converted to `$ipv6` so you know you've got that bit covered.
- Do not forget to remove the ending `)` for the next four steps:
- Search for all instances of *PHP* `inet_pton(` functions and remove them.
- Search for all instances of *PHP* `inet_ntop(` functions and remove them.
- Search for all instances of *SQL* `INET_ATON(` functions and remove them.
- Search for all instances of *SQL* `INET_NTOA(` functions and remove them.
- Search for all instances of `$ipv6` and ensure that all IP-IN-TO-SQL instances use `INET6_ATON('$ipv6')` and that all instances where IP-FROM-SQL use `INET6_NTOA(ipv6) AS ipv6`.
- Search for all instances of `$row1['ip']` and replace them with `$row1['ipv6']`.
- Ensure that all instances of `$ipv6 =` use the following code (with your database object reference changed): `$ipv6 = (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && strlen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) > 0) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) : mysqli_real_escape_string($db,getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));`.
- Ensure that your tests use *freshly* tested IP addresses instead of potentially botched versions if you are aware that there was something wrong *before* you started debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent example however I noted the following.
That only works if one's version of `mysql` has as function for `INET6_ATON`.
Otherwise the error message might be something like:  That `FUNCTION` `DOES` `NOT` `EXIST`.

Comment: You are corrrect and my vesion is really old and does not have that ability: (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41)