# PHP & MySQL: IP addresses like 0.0.7.102

Tags: php, mysql, ipv6, ipv4

I have a a bit of code in my PHP which tries to get the user's IP address:

```
// Test if it is a shared client
if (! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $userIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
// Is it a proxy address?
elseif (! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $userIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else {
    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Then I store `$userIP` in a MySQL table using the `INET_ATON()` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) to convert the string to an integer. I can retrieve this value using MySQL's `INET_NTOA()` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa).

It works perfectly most of the time. **However**, sometimes I get an IP like `0.0.7.102`, for example.

I know these functions don't work with IPv6, but could this problem be caused by something else? Are there a lot of people using IPv6 already? How do I deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the input when you get that output?

Comment: If ipv6 is the problem. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964143/storing-ipv6-addresses-in-mysql

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, since this happens very seldom and I only noticed it today, I don't know what the input is (what PHP's `$_SERVER` variable is returning). I'd have to write a log function to find out... If you mean the integer stored in my table, it is `1894`. Other resolved IPs usually are 10 digits long...

Comment: Please keep in mind that the X-Forwarded-For header can be spoofed trivially, and you should *not* trust it.

Comment: Make sure the field you are storing the IP on your MySQL is `int unsigned`

Comment: @Prix, yep, that's what I'm using. Thanks!