# How to store ip (client) on database without risks

Tags: mysql, ip

I thought to varchar(39) to store all kinds of ip (ipv4, ipv6), but I have pointed out that there are also the IPv4-mapped IPv6, so now I think of varchar(45). There ip longer than 45 characters? If I put varchar(45), are 100% sure that the client will not have a ip longer than 45 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to store IPv6-compatible address in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database)

[Storing IPv6 Addresses in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964143/storing-ipv6-addresses-in-mysql)

[Maximum length of the textual representation of an IPv6 address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address)

There are many similar question.

Comment: I read all those questions, but now I asked if there ip with more than 45 characters.