# How to store a socket.io ipv6 to mysql?

Tags: mysql, socket.io

When running any of these methods on socket.io

```
        console.log('Ip:', socket.request.connection);
        console.log('client IP: ',socket.handshake.address);
        console.log('client IP: ',socket.client.conn.remoteAddress);
        console.log('client IP: ',socket.conn.remoteAddress);
```

They all give me the result: 
**::ffff:86.228.xx.yy**
I guess it is a ipv6 result.

I try to store that with mysql INET6_ATON("::ffff:86.228.xx.yy") and this gives me the result of NULL

What is the proper way to store a socket.io IP address into mysql (as INTEGER) ?

Maybe convert that to a proper ipv6 address ?

Comment: does it really have to be stored as number?

Comment: `::ffff:86.228.xx.yy` doesn't look like an ipv6 address

Comment: xx & yy are the problems - to use INET6_ATON it needs to be a valid IP address

Comment: For the storage type take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964143/storing-ipv6-addresses-in-mysql)

Comment: come on ! I put xx and yy to hide my IP  !!!