# How to compare IPV6 address in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ipv6, ipv4

Here is the IPV6 address in a table in SQL database,
I want to compare these two IPV6 addresses
**From Range: 2002:4559:1FE2:4559:1FE2:21E3:F3E3:0051

To Range: 2002:4559:1FE2:4559:1FE2:21E3:F3E3:0055**
Need to compare those addresses and then update the 
To range address to the From range address in that table.Please help

Comment: there are other options than this two? In future? Or only two addresses to make that range?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL >5.6.3, you could use [INET6_ATON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) to convert the string to a `VARBINARY(16)` and use that for a range check? A lexicographical string comparison might also work for you if these are addresses are all stored in a uniform way.

See also [Storing IPv6 Addresses in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964143/storing-ipv6-addresses-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,But i didnt get you sir,COuld you plz write a querey instead

Answer (score -2):

Calculates an MD5 128-bit checksum for the two ranges and compare the checksum instead the ranges. The value(checksum) is returned as a string of 32 hexadecimal digits, or `NULL` if the argument was `NULL`.

Sample query:

```
UPDATE Table T1
SET T1.To_Range = T1.From_Range
WHERE MD5(T1.From_Range) !=  MD5(T1.To_Range)
```

Comment: Does this MD5 compares the IPV6 addresses?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Im using MySql database